# Do attacks from Bag of Tricks creatures count as magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, damage-resistance

In our last session, the party was fighting a [Ghost](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ghost). A ghost has, among other characteristics, damage resistance to "Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks". The Druid had previously used her [Bag of Tricks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-tricks) to create a [Giant Boar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-boar).

**When the Giant Boar attacks the Ghost with its Tusk, does that count as a "magical attack" and thereby that the Ghost's damage resistance won't apply?**

The standard reference that I've found for figuring out if an attack is magical is in the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), which has this to say under "Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?":

> Determining whether a game feature is magical is straightforward. Ask yourself these questions about the feature:
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the eﬀects of a spell
>     that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature is magical.

I'm not sure, though, if this qualifies as "is it a magic item", as the creature is just created *by* a magic item, but it certainly seems to be a magical sort of creature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A creature created from the bag of tricks is a creature with a stat block. Its attacks are described in the stat block.

> When the object lands, it transforms into a creature [...] See the Monsters Listing for the creature's statistics.

For the example given of a Giant Boar, the attack is slashing damage.

> ***Tusk.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +5 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit:* 10 (2d6 + 3) slashing damage.

A creature is NOT a magical item.